# GPU plugged into a x16 PCIe with 4 available lanes, will it work?

Tags: gpu, pci-express, nvidia-quadro

I'm considering a configuration with a [µATX motherboard (Fujitsu, with Intel Q87 chipset)](http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/products/computing/peripheral/mainboards/extended-lifecycle-main/pmod_135945.html) that has two PCI express x16 slots, one would be occupied by a card that needs the 16 lanes, and the second slot is for a GPU (probably the NVidia Quadro K4000). However there are only 4 lanes left for the second slot. Will the GPU work in this configuration?

I don't need the full bandwidth for the GPU, only the computing power, for CUDA computing power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCI Express specification allows using less lanes than the maximum. So, in principle you should be able to use cards that way.

However, there could be implementation issues, which cause it not to work.

Comment: I could get a confirmation of this from a NVidia reseller: bandwidth is reduced, but the card is still functioning.